# How to take input from an excel or csv file and fetch data from a webpage using python and selenium one by one?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium

I have a web page where I need to enter number of site one by one and fetch data for each of those sites. The site names are kept in an excel column. I am trying to automate this thing using python and selenium and stuck at this step.

I am absolute beginner and working on my first automation project and need help. I am able to login to web page using selenium and click on the tab that pops the window to enter site name.

A sample code with some explanation will be very useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) First, you have to save your excel to csv, it is the easiest way to import data from excel to python,

2) Second, you have to import your column with sites names using csv library to a list, for example:

```py
import csv

list = []

def read_csv(file_path):
    with open(file_path) as f:
        csv_content = csv.DictReader(f)
        for row in csv_content:
            global list
            list.append(row['sitesNamesColumn'])

read_csv('pathToYourFile') # better to keep file in a project
```

3) Third, you have to type the site`s name to some input:

```py
for site in list:
    #click on the tab that pops the window to enter the site name
    input.send_keys(site)
    #fetch data
```